# How can I output to the parent console window from a Win32 C++ application?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

I have a WinAPI/Win32 application. If I try to use cin/cout/cerr when it is run from a command prompt, it doesn't work. I tried switching the project type from Windows Application to Console Application, but the problem is that a console window appears when I run it normally by double-clicking the executable.

So my question is: Is there any way I can use cin/cout/cerr with the parent (calling) console window in a Win32 application? (I only want this behaviour if parameter `/c` or `/?` were passed, so if it is called with no arguments then no matter what it should launch the GUI).

Comment: If you want to use standard input and ouput, you need a console window. It's not clear what you are asking about here.

Comment: if I run the program from a console window, I want the program to output to that same console. cin, cout and cerr just don't seem to work. That is the problem I want to solve

Comment: If you create a console application, that is what it will do.

Comment: Yes, but when the program is run normally and is set as console app, it will display a console window in the background, which is something I don't want. I only want it to use a console when it is run from one.

Comment: So, to be clear, if the application is launched from the console, you want the output to go to that console. If the application is launched from something like explorer, you don't want a console at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A GUI app does not have a console window attached to it by default.

When a GUI app is run from a console process, the GUI app can use [`AttachConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) to attach itself to the console.

Or, if the GUI app is not run from a console process, but still wants to use a console window, it can create its own console window using [`AllocConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole).

Once the GUI app is attached to a console, it can use [`GetStdHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) to get handles to the console's STDIN/STDOUT, and then redirect `cin`/`cout` to use them (how is dependent on your particular STL implementation).

Or, you can ignore `cin`/`cout` and just use [`ReadConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) and [`WriteConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) directly instead.