# How to show and output to the console (cmd) on Windows (C++ WinApi) under `SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I have seen windows applications that operate with both a Window and a console. I find myself wondering about this every now and then and I remember whenever I do research it I never find a solution.

Is there a way to program my WinApi C++ application such that I can output to the console as I would normally do when under the linker option `SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`? In other words I can have a Window open, with my `WinMain` and `WndProc` etc. but I would also like to do `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::wcout`.. A good use-case for that, would be to use the console for logging stuff and the Window as the main application.

Would It be a good idea to use `std::system()` instead and launch `cmd` from that and then output? I don't think so, but of course I don't know.

Windows 8.1, x86_64, MSVS 2017.

Comment: `AllocConsole winapi` is a search phrase you'll find useful.

Comment: Related: [How can I output to the parent console window from a Win32 C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825867/)

Comment: There are many posts related to this and it turns out to be hard to do as you might hope, and always hack. Some websearch will find many results. If you want to log, use a different solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AttachConsole` to attach to an existing console, or `AllocConsole` to create a new console. Then redirect `cin`/`cout` to that console as needed (depending on the requirements of your compiler's particular runtime implementation). Or, just use `ReadConsole`/`WriteConsole` instead.

Comment: This looks hacky. Would it be too much to ask for sample code? Thanks for answering.

Comment: @Nik-Lz a non-console app writing to a console is hacky to begin with. And there are plenty of examples of the functions I mentioned if you Google them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set the subsystem to WINDOWS and /ENTRY (entry point) to `WinMainCRTStartup` (or `wWinMainCRTStartup` if you're using unicode). You can even set it only for the Debug configuration, so the console won't appear for the Release.